# Append Query String via Apache Rewrite Rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite the following:

http://www.mydomain.com/my-page.html to http://www.mydomain.com/my-page.html?type=1

Tried the following without any luck:

```
RewriteRule /car-covers.html$ /car-covers.html?type=$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^car-covers.html$ car-covers.html?type=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^html page/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?action=search_refine&type=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `RewriteRule` you can only test the URI path but not the query. You need to use `RewriteCond` to do so, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY} !(^|&)type=
RewriteRule ^car-covers\.html$ car-covers.html?type=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will add the parameter *type* to the query and do an internal rewrite. If you want an external redirect, add the *R* flag.