# .htaccess rewrite to add query parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I need to modify all requests bearing the form

```
http://example.com/dw2/dokuwiki/doku.php/page to

http://example.com/dw2/dokuwiki/doku.php/page?do=export_xhtml
```

The *page* bit is variable - it corresponds to each paage in the wiki. I should mention that given the way dokuwiki syntax works *page* could contain one or more colons.  e.g. glossary:archive.

The intent here is to extract the bare page content (shorn of the header, sidebar etc) of the wiki for distribution via a CDN.  This does not give a complete solution since dokuwiki still leaves in a lot of unrequired verbiage in the exported markup file but gets me most of the way there.  I'd much appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887496/append-query-string-via-apache-rewrite-rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule as your very first rule in `/dw2/dokuwiki/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dw2/dokuwiki/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(doku\.php/[^/]+)/?$ $1?do=export_xhtml [L,NC,QSA,R,NE]
```